# How to go to an xaml page by clicking on the button in WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 7 or 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, browser

I have a XAML Page with a WebBrowser tag. **WebBrowser has few text boxes and a button, here my question is after clicking on that button i have to go to a XAML page. How can i do this?**

By clicking the button in WebBrowser, i want to go to a XAML Page which is in solution file.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this by listening to the `WebBrowser.Navigating` event. First do:

```
myWebBrowser.Navigating += myWebBrowser_Navigating;
```

Then in the handler method check if the uri navigated to is the pointed to by that button:

```
private void myWebBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e) 
{
    if(e.Uri.AbsolutePath == URI_OF_BUTTON) {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/otherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sound like `Page Navigation`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

      NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pasta.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

}
```